# Join ranges between blank cells using arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to join values till blank cell is reached and iterate it for range.

I know I can use something like `JOIN(",",A2: INDEX(A2:A,MATCH(TRUE,(A2:A=""),0)-1))` for one cell, but I want to know how to use `arrayformula` to apply it for each cell.

```
    A   B
1       A,B,C
2   A   
3   B   
4   C   
5       D,E
6   D   
7   E   
8       F
9   F
```

Column A is the target and B1 is where the `arrayformula` will be applied.

Comment: Will there be just 1 blank cell between filled  rows?

Comment: There can be more than one blank cells. So the formula will skip the current cell if the next cell is also empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(,
  SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",0,A2:A11),",{2,}","™"),"™")&
  SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(,,IF((A1:A11="")*(A2:A12<>""),"♞","✦")),"♞")&"✦"
),"✦",1,0)))
```

- A1 must be blank.
- Multiple `JOIN/SPLIT` combo is used, where you join a range and then split a range to create a new range moulded to our will.
- Essentially, the formula creates two arrays:

  - Data array represented by col A

    ```
    A,B,C| E,D| F
    ```
  - Corresponding Space array: The number of spaces needed between each of the above data

    ```
    ✦✦✦✦| ✦✦✦| ✦✦
    ```
- JOIN/SPLIT both arrays and  TRANSPOSE them to get your col B array.